# mustUnderstand Attribute not just set to false.

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java, envelope

I have done a ton of research and cant find anything that specifically fixes my problem.

I generated my SOAP client with wsdl2java, The problem is that my envelope, when sent out, creates attributes in the HeaderElement that i need to not be there.

I have created a handler to build my header but have been unable to strip these attributes out of the header.

Sample XML going out.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://..."
xmlns:v2="http://..."
xmlns:xsd="http://..." xmlns:xsi="...">
<soapenv:Header>
    <v2:wsMessageHeader soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
        soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
        <v2:trackingMessageHeader>
            <values>....</values>
        </v2:trackingMessageHeader>
    </v2:wsMessageHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <item 
        xmlns="http://...">
        <geoCode>Zip</geoCode>
        <zip>
            <uspsPostalCd>49001</uspsPostalCd>
        </zip>
    </item>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I need the soapenv:actor and the soapenv:mustUnderstand attributes to be completely removed.

Answer (score -1):

SOAP Header is optional element..You should be able to remove it..

```
messagecontext.getEnvelope().getHeader().detach();
```

No need to do ton of research :)